# casting raw strings python

Tags: python, string

Given a variable which holds a string is there a quick way to cast that into another raw string variable?

The following code should illustrate what I'm after:

```
line1 = "hurr..\n..durr"
line2 = r"hurr..\n..durr"

print(line1 == line2)  # outputs False
print(("%r"%line1)[1:-1] == line2)  # outputs True
```

The closest I have found so far is the `%r` formatting flag which seems to return a raw string albeit within single quote marks. Is there any easier way to do this kind of thing?

Comment: The reason you can't "cast" into a raw string is that there **aren't** "raw strings"; there are raw string **literals**, which are **only** a *different syntax for creating strings*. The data is the **same type**: `str`. The question is really about how to convert sequences *of text* in the original string, into *other sequences of text*.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

**Python 3:**

```
"hurr..\n..durr".encode('unicode-escape').decode()
```

**Python 2:**

```
"hurr..\n..durr".encode('string-escape')
```

Comment: nice one. str.encode() with the various codecs is exactly what i was after. 'unicode-escape' actually solves another problem i was having too. cheers

Comment: This doesn't work for `\w` etc.

Comment: I'm getting an error in Python3.3

LookupError: unknown encoding: string-escape

Comment: @Erik, strings in Python 3 are Unicode, use `unicode-escape`.

Comment: Don't forget that you can decode the resultant bytes into a regular Unicode string (still escaped, if you don't supply any parameters in Python 3.x), instead of still using a byte string.

Comment: @gnibbler, There doesn't appear to be `\w` in Python. What are you referring to? Maybe you're thinking of regular expressions.

Comment: Fails for `"X \x58"`

Answer (score 2):

Yet another way:

```
>>> s = "hurr..\n..durr"
>>> print repr(s).strip("'")
hurr..\n..durr
```

Comment: That won't work if `s` has a `'` in it

Comment: It should be ok if the `'` is in the middle of the string, but it's definitely not robust (it's screwy with Unicode strings, for example).

Comment: @Seth No, it will not, because if you have `'` contained in the data then the repr will have used double quotes instead of single quotes at the edges of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Above it was shown how to encode.

```
'hurr..\n..durr'.encode('string-escape')
```

This way will decode.

```
r'hurr..\n..durr'.decode('string-escape')
```

Ex.

```
In [12]: print 'hurr..\n..durr'.encode('string-escape')
hurr..\n..durr

In [13]: print r'hurr..\n..durr'.decode('string-escape')
hurr..
..durr
```

This allows one to "cast/trasform raw strings" in both directions. A practical case is when the json contains a raw string and I want to print it nicely.

```
{
    "Description": "Some lengthy description.\nParagraph 2.\nParagraph 3.",
    ...
}
```

I would do something like this.

```
print json.dumps(json_dict, indent=4).decode('string-escape')
```