# Valid JSON giving JSONDecodeError: Expecting , delimiter

Tags: python, json, escaping, rawstring

I'm trying to parse a json response data from youtube api but i keep getting an error.

Here is the snippet where it choking:

```
data = json.loads("""{ "entry":{ "etag":"W/\"A0UGRK47eCp7I9B9WiRrYU0.\"" } }""")
```

..and this happens:

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting , delimiter: line 1 column 23 (char 23)
```

I've confirmed that it's valid json and I have no control over the formatting of it so how can I get past this error?

Comment: Also you might want to check your json if all lines end with commas except the last line

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You'll need a `r` before """, or replace all `\` with `\\`. This is not something you should care about when read the json from somewhere else, but something in the string itself.

`data = json.loads(r"""{ "entry":{ "etag":"W/\"A0UGRK47eCp7I9B9WiRrYU0.\"" } }""")`

see [here](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html) for more information

Comment: Ok but you need to explain why. The input needs to be passed a rawstring to avoid the `\"` backslash-escape being misinterpreted.

Comment: what's the solution if the string is stored in a variable?

Comment: Store in it a variable as a rawstring

Comment: How to store json in a variable as a raw string? @JacobBayer

Comment: @sheth7 `raw_json = r"""{ "entry":{...}}"""`

Comment: `raw_s = r'{}'.format(s)`, `fr"{orignal_string}"` [convert-regular-python-string-to-raw-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415259/convert-regular-python-string-to-raw-string), [string-and-bytes-literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals)

Answer (score 19):

You need to add `r` before your json string.

```
>>> st = r'{ "entry":{ "etag":"W/\"A0UGRK47eCp7I9B9WiRrYU0.\"" } }'
>>> data = json.loads(st)
>>>
```

Comment: I think it's better to use """ instead of ' to enclose the json because the data can have unescaped single quotes in it. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @ofko: I know that I just wrote this for clarity.