# Parsing Json Strings with escaped double quotes

Tags: python, json, python-3.5

I need to work with a lot of json strings as byte objects that look like this:

```
json_string = b'{"a":"1","b":"2","c":"abc=\"d\""}'.decode('utf8')
```

when I put them through `json.loads()`

```
json_object = json.loads(json_string)
```

it fails because the double quotes are not correctly escaped. How do I replace the `\` with a `\\` and is there another option than replacing all `\` with `\\`? Because at other positions in the string it might be unwanted to replace them. The real `json strings` are longer and more complex than in the example here.

I use python 3.5

Comment: That's not JSON. Insist that whoever is sending you strings like that fix their own code, rather than forcing you to write hacky workarounds for the mess they've made.

Comment: How do these non-json strings come to exist?

Comment: They origin from WAT files and contain http(s) headers an example for one of the "real" key value pairs that make trouble look like this: `,"Connection":"close","p3p":"CP=\"CAO PSA OUR\"","cache-control":"no-store",`

Comment: According to this it should work with single \ https://stackoverflow.com/a/15637481/3254405

Comment: Sadly it does not it fails with the following exception `JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 1410 (char 1409)` unless i delete the key value pair. Which is not an option if have to parse millions of them

Comment: What if you don't decode and just load the json string.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/20199213/3254405

Comment: If I wrap the string into a file stream like this: `json_io = io.StringIO((json_string))` I still get the same exception when I then try to load it with `json.load(json_io)` .

Comment: Try putting r inside loads again (not load): https://stackoverflow.com/a/9156466/3254405

Comment: adding `r` in front of the string does the trick and I can load the json simply with `json.loads()`