# Valid JSON giving JSONDecodeError: Expecting , delimiter (2)

Tags: json, python-3.x

I am trying to load a json-like string using the json library:

```
data = json.loads(raw_json.replace(" ","").replace("\n",""))
```

However I get the following error:

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter
```

I looked at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9156417/valid-json-giving-jsondecodeerror-expecting-delimiter?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) but it doesn't seem to help... also I have no idea howto convert my string to a raw string using its variable name... The only problem that I can see in my raw_json variable is that it has a lot of spaces and newlines. My raw_json variable looks like this:

```
{

"search": {
"levier": "Recherchedepuislaliste",
"nbresults": "137 314",
"nbpage": "1",
"typedetransaction": ["vente", "viager"],
"nbpieces": [""],
"typedebien": ["Appartement", "Maison/Villa"],
"pays": "FR",
"nbchambres": [""],
"budget": {"min": "", "max": ""},
"surface": {"min": "", "max": ""},
"surface_terrain": {"min": "", "max": ""},
"type": [{"name": "Nouvellerecherche", "value": true},
        {"name": "Dernièrerecherche", "value": false},
        {"name": "Rechercheenregistrée", "value": false}],
"etage": {"min": "", "max": ""},
"tri": {"criteria": "Sélection",
        "direction": ""},
"chauffage": [{"name": "individuel", "value": false},
              {"name": "central", "value": false},
              {"name": "electrique", "value": false},
              {"name": "gaz", "value": false}]
}
```

Comment: Its a broken json data. Put the entire example .. Closing tag missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is everything correct except that the closing bracket is missing, just add an `}` to the end of your JSON-object.

Comment: Thanks lustigo ! That was exactly the problem !