# Adding 'r' to json string from file python

Tags: python, json

I am facing with the following error while reading json from file

```
    json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 2 column 1 (char 948)
```

The json content is read from file using the script below

```
import json
if __name__ == "__main__":

     file_path = "D:\\Freelancing\\Scraping_football_historic_data\\Data\\1.138103502"

     with open(file_path,'r') as datafile:

         dict_data = json.load(datafile)

     print(dict_data)
```

Upon searching for answer, this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9156417/valid-json-giving-jsondecodeerror-expecting-delimiter) had an answer that suggested me to add **r** before the json string.

How can it be done in the case above, or if there's a better way to read the file. ?

The contents of the file can be read from the pastebin link:
https://pastebin.com/ZyyrtcZW

Comment: The data in the file is not valid JSON; it looks like each line should maybe have a trailing comma. Adding `r` won't help anything.

Comment: the comma's are to represent list of dicts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a comma between each of your individual dictionaries, your data should look like

```
....
{"op":"mcm","clk":"5733948534","pt":1514206953689,"mc":[{"id":"1.138103502","rc":[{"ltp":2.02,"id":48756}]}]},
{"op":"mcm","clk":"5739085003","pt":1514309273736,"mc":[{"id":"1.138103502","rc":[{"ltp":2.0,"id":48756}]}]},
{"op":"mcm","clk":"5739711407","pt":1514327265235,"mc":[{"id":"1.138103502","rc":[{"ltp":2.06,"id":48756}]}]},
.....
```