# How to convert a variable to a raw string?

Tags: python-3.x, string

If I have a string, `"foo; \n"`, I can turn this into a raw string with `r"foo; \n"`. If I have a variable `x = "foo; \n"`, how do I convert `x` into a raw string? I tried `y = rf"{x}"` but this did not work.

**Motivation:**

I have a python string variable, `res`. I compute res as

```
big_string = """foo; ${bar}"""
from string import Template
t = Template(big_string)
res = t.substitute(bar="baz")
```

As such, `res` is a variable. I'd like to convert this variable into a raw string. The reason is I am going to POST it as JSON, but I am getting `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 620 (char 619)`. Previously, when testing I fixed this by converting my string to a raw string with: `x = r"""foo; baz"""` (keeping in line with the example above). Now I am not dealing with a big raw string. I am dealing with a variable that is a JSON representation of a string where I have replaced a single variable, `bar` above, with a list for a query, and now I want to convert this string into a raw string (e.g. `r"foo; baz"`, yes I realize this is not valid JSON).

Update: As per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9156417/valid-json-giving-jsondecodeerror-expecting-delimiter) I need a raw string. [The question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415259/convert-regular-python-string-to-raw-string) flagged in the comments as duplicate do not work (`res.encode('unicode_escape')`).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert regular Python string to raw string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415259/convert-regular-python-string-to-raw-string)

Comment: This seems like it might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832), so if that doesn't answer your question, please provide a [mre], and we can help you debug.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415259/convert-regular-python-string-to-raw-string) help?

Comment: No, thanks. Unfortunately `res.encode('unicode_escape') did not work.