# Python Running OS command with quotes inside

Tags: python-2.7, operating-system

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os

readLine = open('desktops.txt','r')

for line in readLine:
        machineName = line
        query = os.system('wmic -U corp.fakedomain.com/domainusername%password //192.168.1.100 "Select * from Win32_UserAccount Where LocalAccount = True"|grep "500|"|cut -d "\\" -f 2|cut -d "|" -f1')
```

I am receiving the following error...

myhostname:~# ./getLocalAdminNames.py
sh: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
sh: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
sh: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
sh: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
sh: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string

Then after I resolve the error I would like to substitute the IP with machineName variable.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try printing the string you send to `os.system` to find out if you got the quoting right. Or better, just run `wmic` and do the rest (`grep` and `cut`) in Python, it'll make your life a lot easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should escape your backslashes. Replace `\\` with `\\\\`:

```
os.system('wmic -U corp.fakedomain.com/domainusername%password //192.168.1.100 "Select * from Win32_UserAccount Where LocalAccount = True"|grep "500|"|cut -d "\\\\" -f 2|cut -d "|" -f1')
```

or, make your string `raw` by adding `r` prefix:

```
os.system(r'wmic -U corp.fakedomain.com/domainusername%password //192.168.1.100 "Select * from Win32_UserAccount Where LocalAccount = True"|grep "500|"|cut -d "\\" -f 2|cut -d "|" -f1')
```

Also see:

- [What exactly do "u" and "r" string flags do in Python, and what are raw string literals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-rstring-flags-in-python-and-what-are-raw-string-litte)
- [Python Raw Strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415259/python-raw-strings)

Comment: Thank you! That worked but now each machine in that variable will be a hostname. I seem to be having a problem using the following... os.system(r'wmic -U corp.fakedomain.com/domainuser%domainpass //'+machineName+' "Select * from Win32_UserAccount Where LocalAccount = True"|grep "500|"|cut -d "\\" -f 2|cut -d "|" -f1')