# Python: Finding values after searching for a string in a text files

Tags: python, text-files

I'm new to the world of python and I'm trying to extract values from multiple text files. I can open up the files fine with a loop, but I'm looking for a straight forward way to search for a string and then return the value after it.

My results text files look like this

```
SUMMARY OF RESULTS
Max tip rotation =,-18.1921,degrees
Min tip rotation =,-0.3258,degrees
Mean tip rotation =,-7.4164,degrees
Max tip displacement =,6.9956,mm
Min tip displacement =,0.7467,mm
Mean tip displacement = ,2.4321,mm
Max Tsai-Wu FC =,0.6850
Max Tsai-Hill FC =,0.6877
```

So I want to be able to search for say 'Max Tsai-Wu =,' and it return 0.6850 
I want to be able to search for the string as the position of each variable might change at a later date.

Sorry for posting such an easy question, just can't seem to find a straight forward robust way of finding it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Matt

Comment: fairly small, maybe about 200 lines at most

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of regex:

```
import re


regexp = re.compile(r'Max Tsai-Wu.*?([0-9.-]+)')
with open('input.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        match = regexp.match(line)
        if match:
            print match.group(1)
```

prints:

```
0.6850
```

UPD: getting results into the list

```
import re


regexp = re.compile(r'Max Tsai-Wu.*?([0-9.-]+)') 
result = []
with open('input.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        match = regexp.match(line)
        if match:
            result.append(match.group(1))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Could I just ask what does the r before the Max Tsai-Wu do? Also the .*?([0-9.-]+)?

Comment: @user2739143, sure, `r` means it's just a [raw string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415259/python-raw-strings). `.*?([0-9.-]+)`: `.*?` here means non-greedy match for any set of characters - in this case it will match anything between `Max Tsai-Wu` and your float number, `([0-9.-]+)` is a capturing group for the float number you want to extract.

Comment: Can I just ask one more question!
Say I want to create a list of all the values taken from that loop, how would I make a list with all the values, i.e. something like this

listOfMaxTipRotation = listOfMaxTipRotation , maxTipRotation

Comment: Sorry to keep bothering you just got another quick question. I'm trying to export the data obtained to a CSV file, but when I export it, the lists still have the [] either side of the lists. How do I get rid of them? Also each value has '' either side, how do I remove them? Thank you!

Comment: I have one text file on many lines of contact names separated with their phone numbers by comma. I need to search for the matching contact name when the user inputs and displays the relevant phone number. How to associate this script with React Native android app?

Answer (score 1):

My favorite way is to test if the line starts with the desired text:

> ```
> keyword = 'Max Tsai-Wu' 
> if line.startswith(keyword):
> ```

And then split the line using the commas and return the value

> ```
> try:
>     return float(line.split(',')[1])
> except ValueError:
>     # treat the error
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression to find both name and value:

```
import re

RE_VALUE = re.compile('(.*?)\s*=,(.*?),')

def test():
    line = 'Max tip rotation =,-18.1921,degrees'
    rx = RE_VALUE.search(line)
    if rx:
        print('[%s] value: [%s]' % (rx.group(1), rx.group(2)))


test()
```

This way reading file line by line you can fill some dictionary.

My regex uses fact that value is between commas.

Answer (score 0):

If the files aren't that big, you could simply do:

```
import re
files = [list, of, files]
for f in files:
    with open(f) as myfile:
        print re.search(r'Max Tsai-Wu.*?=,(.+)', myfile.read()).group(1)
```