# inserting variable into regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write code that can extract values from variables in a text file.

so if the file was
`"bob= 1255 mike = 13"`

when I specified bob as `var_name` it would extract `1255`, and so on.

based my code off of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18714724/python-finding-values-after-searching-for-a-string-in-a-text-files) but it doesnt seem to be working

```
var_name = 'bob'

regexp = re.compile(r''+var_name+'.*?([0-9.-]+)')

with open("textfile") as s:
    for line in s:
        match = regexp.match(line)
        if match:
            print(match.group(1))

var_name = 'mike'

regexp = re.compile(r''+var_name+'.*?([0-9.-]+)')

with open("textfile") as s:
    for line in s:
        match = regexp.match(line)
        if match:
            print(match.group(1))
```

Comment: Have you tried `match = regexp.match(line.strip())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `re.match`, which only finds things at the start of the string (and `mike` is not at the start of the string). Use `re.search`, which finds things at any position.

---

Slightly off-topic: Note that `r'...'` does not mean "regexp literal". It means "raw string literal". The purpose of it is to avoid having to escape backslashes inside the string. Now, `''` very obviously does not contain any backslashes, so `r''` is not at all different from `''`. On the other hand, `.*?([0-9.-]+)` is complex enough that we are not sure whether or not there are (or will be) any backslashes in it - and yet you don't make it into a raw string literal. Puzzling. :) I would have written `var_name + r'.*?([0-9.-]+)'`, without the useless `r'' +`...

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention what does work / what does not work.

Instead of `.*?` you should use `\s*=\s*`. Otherwise you can catch things like `#edsakjj*kjn` - and I assume you do not want this.

You may also make sure that the number is really a number: `-?\d+(\.?\d+)?`: optional - (minus, for negative numbers), mandatory digit(s), optionally: decimal mark followed by digit(s).

[Test regex](https://regex101.com/r/BmNr9C/1)

Regarding python code, I am not your guy, sorry :(