# Why is raw string performing inconsistently in parenthesis

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

For example:

```
a = (r'''\n1''')

b = (r'''
2''')

print(a)
print(b)
```

The output of this example is this:

```
\n1

2
```

Meaning that even if `b` is supposed to be a raw string, it does not seem to work like one, why is this?

I also checked:

```
if '\n' in b:
    print('yes')
```

The output of this is `yes` meaning that b is a string, and indeed has `\n` string inside of it.

Comment: Why is this inconsistent? *Escape sequences* don't work, but an actual newline is not an escape sequence.

Comment: Don't use a triple-quoted string when you don't want extra whitespace, tabs and newlines.

Comment: Can read more about that in the docs. https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals and this SO answer http://stackoverflow.com/q/4415259/4099593

Comment: Your question is missing any counter example of what you expected to happen instead, or why you thought this was caused by the parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the raw string syntax, *escape sequences* have no special meaning (apart from a backslash before a quote). The characters `\` plus `n` form two characters in a raw string literal, unlike a regular string literal, where those two characters are replaced by a newline character.

An actual newline character, on the other hand, is *not an escape sequence*. It is just a newline character, and is included in the string as such.

Compare this to using `1` versus `\x31`; the latter is an escape sequence for the ASCII codepoint for the digit `1`. In a regular string literal, both would give you the character `1`, in a raw string literal, the escape sequence would not be interpreted:

```
>>> print('1\x31')
11
>>> print(r'1\x31')
1\x31
```

All this has nothing to do with parentheses. The parentheses do not alter the behaviour of a `r'''...'''` raw string. The *exact same thing* happens when you remove the parentheses:

```
>>> a = r'''\n1'''
>>> a
'\\n1'
>>> print(a)
\n1
>>> b = r'''
... 2'''
>>> b
'\n2'
>>> print(b)

2
```