# Add 'r' prefix to a python variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-prefix

I have string variable which is

```
temp = '1\2\3\4'
```

I would like to add a prefix 'r' to the string variable and get

```
r'1\2\3\4'
```

so that I can split the string based on '\'. I tried the following:

```
r'temp'
'r' + temp
r + temp
```

But none of the above works. Is there a simple to do it? I'm using python 3. I also tried to encode the string, using

```
temp.encode('string-escape')
```

But it returns the following error

```
LookupError: unknown encoding: string-escape
```

Comment: How are the strings being created in the first place? If you are doing it in your code, just add the `r` yourself in the code?  If you are getting the input from the user, then the user needs to input the correct string in the first place.

Comment: The string is actually a file location that is generated using glob.iglob () function. I would like to get all the txt file in a certain file, and I would like to extract the name of those files by splitting '\'.

Comment: @SethMMorton, see my comments above. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: The results of `glob.iglob()` should not suffer any escaping problem trying to do this post-escape isn't necessary.

Comment: @SethMMorton Ah... I see. Yeah, it works. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert regular Python string to raw string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415259/convert-regular-python-string-to-raw-string)

Answer (score 9):

`r` is a prefix for string *literals*. This means, `r"1\2\3\4"` will not interpret `\` as an escape when creating the string value, but keep `\` as an actual character in the string. Thus, `r"1\2\3\4"` will have seven characters.

You already have the string value: there is nothing to interpret. You cannot have the `r` prefix affect a variable, only a literal.

Your `temp = "1\2\3\4"` will interpret backslashes as escapes, create the string `'1\x02\x03\x04'` (a four-character string), then assign this string to the variable `temp`. There is no way to retroactively reinterpret the original literal.

EDIT: In view of the more recent comments, you do not seem to, in fact, have a string `"1\2\3\4"`. If you have a valid path, you can split it using

```
path.split(r'\')
```

or

```
path.split('\\')
```

but you probably also don't need that; rather, you may want to split a path into directory and file name, which is best done by [`os.path` functions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html).

Comment: Then how can I split the string variable? I would like to have results like ['1', '2', '3', '4']. I know I can do with r'1\2\3\4', but not '1\2\3\4'

Comment: There is nothing to split. `"1\2\3\4"` does not contain the characters `2`, `3` or `4`.

Answer (score 4):

Wouldn't it just be `re.escape(temp)`?

Take for example the use case of trying to generate a pattern on the fly involving word boundaries.  Then you can do this

```
r'\b' + re.escape(temp) + r'\b'
```

Answer (score -4):

just to prefix r in variable in search, Please do this r+""+temp.
e.g.-

```
import re
email_address = 'Please contact us at: support@datacamp.com'
searchString = "([\w\.-]+)@([\w\.-]+)"
re.serach(r""+searchString, email_address)
```