# Access denied when using pydub

Tags: python, python-3.x, mp3, wav

I want to use this script to convert a mp3 file to a wav file.

```
import pydub
from pydub import AudioSegment
pydub.AudioSegment.converter=r"C:\Users\sunha\ffmpeg-4.1-win64-static\bin"
sound = AudioSegment.from_mp3("筷子兄弟 - 小苹果.mp3")
sound.export("筷子兄弟 - 小苹果.wav", format="wav")
```

But the problem is my access is denied.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-1-5faa7bcb6b97>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/sunha/project-001/untitled1.py', wdir='C:/Users/sunha/project-001')

File "E:\program\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 786, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

File "E:\program\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "C:/Users/sunha/project-001/untitled1.py", line 4, in <module>
    sound = AudioSegment.from_mp3("筷子兄弟 - 小苹果.mp3")

File "E:\program\lib\site-packages\pydub\audio_segment.py", line 716, in from_mp3
    return cls.from_file(file, 'mp3', parameters=parameters)

File "E:\program\lib\site-packages\pydub\audio_segment.py", line 697, in from_file
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

File "E:\program\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 143, in __init__
    super(SubprocessPopen, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

File "E:\program\lib\subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)

File "E:\program\lib\subprocess.py", line 1178, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)

PermissionError: [WinError 5] 拒绝访问。
```

How can I possibly fix the problem?

Comment: did you check, that you really have permissions for this file?

Comment: I tried to run it as administrator and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I tried out multiple solutions, which helped me, as follows:

- Rebooting the computer and/or IDE,
- Updating Python, IDE, computer,
- **pip install pydirectory** (Command/Anaconda prompt, run as administrator)
- Applying read permissions to the file,
- Specifying the path to the file, and adding 'r' before the path, to indicate you want to 'read' the audio file, example at the bottom.

[Source](https://techisours.com/winerror-5-access-is-denied-fixed-completely/)

Example, run in the same folder as the audio file:

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
import os

os.chmod('audio2.mp3', 777)  #You might not need this

sound = AudioSegment.from_mp3(r"D:/audio.mp3")
#Put the 'r' in front of the filepath, to 'read' the audio file.
sound.export("audio.wav", format="wav")
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and resolved by referencing @artgue72's answer on [Python Pydub Permission denied?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44215734/python-pydub-permission-denied/74968568#74968568):

> I had the same issue but fixed using the GillHawk solution from this thread (same link as Jondiepdoop gave). I added f.close() in the _play_with_ffplay function of the playback.py file:
>
> ```
> def _play_with_ffplay(seg):
> with NamedTemporaryFile("w+b", suffix=".wav") as f:
>     f.close() # close the file stream
>     seg.export(f.name, "wav")
>     subprocess.call([PLAYER, "-nodisp", "-autoexit", "-hide_banner", f.name])
> ```

In addition, please check the folder path is added to Window's Environmental Variables.

In my case, I also need no `r` [string literal symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41155406) before the file path, like:

```
sound = AudioSegment.from_file('C:\\temp\\audio1.mp3', format="mp3").
```