# What is a function for r-prefix?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a function that has an effect of `r'some string'`?

For instance we have some variable `s = 'a:b\nc'`, and we want to escape it somewhere later, so what function can do that?

`re.escape` escapes `:` too, so it isn't equivalent of r-prefix. Basically r-equivalent function should give `a:b\\nc` as a raw string, not `a\:b\\nc`, right?

Comment: I don't think `r` does what you think it does.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Raw Strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415259/python-raw-strings)

Comment: Once a string has already been parsed and is *in memory*, there is no equivalent for `r`. For example, supposed I had, `x = 'an a: \u0041'`, what do you want your function to do to `x`? The value is `x` is equal to the literal `'an a: A'`. If you want `'an a: \\u0041'`, which is what `r` would have done, there's no way to do that since the original literal representation is no longer available to the interpreter. (At least, not without some kind of psycho manual reparsing of a code file or something equally off the wall.) It's not clear what result you want.

Comment: Thought at first that there is mutually correspondence between values in memories and their representations. So you can go in both directions.

Comment: Python's string syntax allows many representations to result in the same string. To extend jpmc26's example, `'A'`, `'\x41'`, `'\u0041'` and `'\U00000041'` all refer to the same character.

Comment: Duplicate: [casting raw strings python](//stackoverflow.com/q/2428117)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably a bit confused about what the raw prefix on a string literal actually does, but I think I understand the question anyway: you want to escape the backslashes.

This was the closest thing I could find.  There is probably a better way:

```
>>> import codecs
>>> s = 'a:b\nc'
>>> codecs.encode(s, 'unicode-escape').decode('utf-8')
'a:b\\nc'
```

Comment: Thanks, tried `codecs.escape_encode` before and it didn't work. Now I understand that before that I should have turned string into bytes. But that would lead to 3 steps, your approach with `codecs.encode` is two.

Comment: It's not clear what the OP wants. Consider the string `'an a: \u0041'`. Does the OP want `'an a: A'` or `'an a: \\u0041'`? Your answer returns the former.

Comment: @jpmc26  You're right, but it's up to them to clarify it if they want any more help...

Comment: This won't work for complicated string which contains weird characters and control characters: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52744656/how-to-format-convert-string-literal-to-raw-string-literal-in-python3-at-run-tim?noredirect=1#comment92414162_52744656