# How to convert a regular string to a raw string?

Tags: python

```
>>> normal="The\n\t\n quick silver fox ran over lazy dog's"
>>> normal
"The\n\t\n quick silver fox ran over lazy dog's" # 1
>>> json.dumps(normal)
'"The\\n\\t\\n quick silver fox ran over lazy dog\'s"'
>>> r"The\n\t\n quick silver fox ran over lazy dog's"
"The\\n\\t\\n quick silver fox ran over lazy dog's"
>>> r"{}".format(normal)
"The\n\t\n quick silver fox ran over lazy dog's"
>>> rf"{normal}"
"The\n\t\n quick silver fox ran over lazy dog's"
```

How can I convert normal string (#1) to raw string (#2) using String Formatting or F-stings

Comment: If you have opportunity to use json module - `json.dumps(normal)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert regular Python string to raw string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415259/convert-regular-python-string-to-raw-string)

Comment: Be sure to see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4415585/355230) to the linked question.

Comment: `>>> json.dumps(normal)
'"The\\n"'`

which is not equivalent to required output `'The\\n'` (# 2)

Comment: `>>> rf"{normal}"
'The\n' ` [Convert regular Python string to raw string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415259/convert-regular-python-string-to-raw-string) this question does not answer my question.