# Convert \"\n string to \\\"\n in Python

Tags: python, c#

I have a string `\"\n` in python and I would like to convert it to `\\\"\n`. How can I do that in general? I need that because I would like to pass this string as an argument to function written in C# since in C# `\\\"\n` string is simply translated to `\"\n`

Comment: If you know what result you expect `(\\\\"\n)` why don't you just return it?

Comment: You might mix up the representation of a string with the real content of the string. Look at the difference of `print(r'\"\n')` and `print(repr(r'\"\n'))`,

Answer (score 0):

I found this link [Convert regular Python string to raw string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415259/convert-regular-python-string-to-raw-string)

```
s = '\"\n'
raw_s = s.encode('unicode-escape').decode().replace('\"', '\\\"')
final_s = raw_s.replace(r'\"\n',r'\\\"\n')

print(s)
print(raw_s)
print(final_s)
```

Output:

```
"

\"\n
\\\"\n
```