# get string from mongodb to python as raw string solved but new problem with parse_latex

Tags: python, mongodb, parsing, sympy, rawstring

i am getting following as string from MongoDB query:

```
1000*\frac{1-{(\frac{1}{1+0.1025})^{10}}}{0.09806}'
```

like to take it to equate to expression

```
expression = '1000*\frac{1-{(\frac{1}{1+0.1025})^{10}}}{0.09806}'
```

then
convert to sympy expression
with

```
expression_fin = parse_latex(expression)
```

but I got errors as this is not a raw string

I tried the following:

```
expression1=f'{expression}'
expression = repr('1000*\frac{1-{(\frac{1}{1+0.1025})^{10}}}{0.09806}')
```

both attempts does not works
please help if any
Edited:

```
    def step_exec(step_id, part_req):
    print('printing here')
    newEq=repr(part_req['extras'][0]['fn_e8wgwASbHjuLR7Mb6mH2pC'])
    print(newEq)
    # rawtest = r'%s' % newEq

    rawtest = parse_expr(newEq, evaluate=False)
    sympy_inputFrom_parse_expr=parse_latex(rawtest)
    print('sympy_inputFrom_parse_expr',sympy_inputFrom_parse_expr)
    latex_inputFromSympy=latex(sympy_inputFrom_parse_expr)
    print('latex_inputFromSympy',latex_inputFromSympy)
    print(latex_inputFromSympy == part_req['extras'][0]['fn_e8wgwASbHjuLR7Mb6mH2pC'])

    pprint.pprint(part_req['extras'][0]['fn_e8wgwASbHjuLR7Mb6mH2pC'])

    print('raw here')
    rawRstring=r'1200*\frac{1-{(\frac{1}{1+0.1259})^{12}}}{0.11917}'
    print('rawRstring',rawRstring)
    parsLatToSympy = parse_latex(rawRstring)
    print('parsLatToSympy',parsLatToSympy)
    SympyTOlatex=latex(parsLatToSympy)
    print('SympyTOlatex',SympyTOlatex)
    print('latex_inputFromSympy', latex_inputFromSympy)

    return step_id
```

the result:

```
printing here
```

'1200*\frac{1-{(\frac{1}{1+0.1259})^{12}}}{0.11917}'

sympy_inputFrom_parse_expr 1200*((1 - 1/(0.1259 + 1)**12)/0.11917)

latex_inputFromSympy 1200 \frac{1 - \frac{1}{\left(0.1259 + 1\right)^{12}}}{0.11917}

False

'1200*\frac{1-{(\frac{1}{1+0.1259})^{12}}}{0.11917}'

raw here

rawRstring 1200*\frac{1-{(\frac{1}{1+0.1259})^{12}}}{0.11917}

parsLatToSympy 1200*((1 - 1/(0.1259 + 1)**12)/0.11917)

SympyTOlatex 1200 \frac{1 - \frac{1}{\left(0.1259 + 1\right)^{12}}}{0.11917}

latex_inputFromSympy 1200 \frac{1 - \frac{1}{\left(0.1259 + 1\right)^{12}}}{0.11917}

the raw string problem is solved from "parse_expr" but it changes the expression
please help if any

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raw string can be created by prefixing a string literal with `r""`. In your case:

```
from sympy.parsing.latex import parse_latex
r_string = r"1000*\frac{1-{(\frac{1}{1+0.1025})^{10}}}{0.09806}"
expression = parse_latex(r_string)
expression
```

EDIT to accommodate comment. Yeah, nice problem you have :) For your specific case you cold do this `s.encode('unicode_escape').decode()`. But this is likely going to modify the characters following backslashes, so you would also have to perform a replacement to bring them back to the original intent. For example:

```
s = "1000*\frac{1-{(\frac{1}{1+0.1025})^{10}}}{0.09806}"
# convert to raw, according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/65380295/2329968
r_string = s.encode('unicode_escape').decode()
# at this point you have a problem: the character inside s following a
# backslash might change to something else. Need to bring it back
r_string_mod = r_string.replace("x0c", "f")
parse_latex(r_string_mod)
```

Comment: its API call I cannot add prefix r to it, its in a variable,  expression = part_req['extras'][0]['fn_e8wgwASbHjuLR7Mb6mH2pC']     where        part_req['extras'][0]['fn_e8wgwASbHjuLR7Mb6mH2pC'] = '1000*\frac{1-{(\frac{1}{1+0.1025})^{10}}}{0.09806}'

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: thanks this works, can you help on the next one as even taking r string to parse_latex, I am getting another problem after conversion it's evaluating some of the parts of the expression or transforming the expression in a different format rather than showing the same

Comment: I suggested opening a new question, as I don't fully understand your last question. I need to see what's going on...

Comment: added, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72611402/sympys-parse-expr-still-evaluates-the-expression-and-same-happens-with-parse-la