# Format LaTeX expression using Python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, latex

I have a poorly formatted LaTeX which needs to be formatted in specific manner to render in Jupyter Notebook correctly:

```py
# Supporting Libraries:
from qiskit.visualization import array_to_latex
from IPython.display import display, Markdown

# Unsuitable LaTeX
latex_baad =  '$QFT = \\frac{1}{\\sqrt{32}} \n\n\\begin{bmatrix}\n0  \\\\\n -1  \\\\\n \\end{bmatrix}\n \\otimes \n\n\\begin{bmatrix}\n0  \\\\\n \\tfrac{1}{\\sqrt{2}}(1 - i)  \\\\\n \\end{bmatrix}\n \\otimes \n\n\\begin{bmatrix}\n0  \\\\\n -0.92388 + 0.38268i  \\\\\n \\end{bmatrix}\n \\otimes \n\n\\begin{bmatrix}\n0  \\\\\n -0.19509 - 0.98079i  \\\\\n \\end{bmatrix}\n$'

# Suitable LaTeX
latex_good = r'$QFT =  \frac{1}{ \sqrt{32}}      \begin{bmatrix}  0  \\     -1          \end{bmatrix}    \otimes      \begin{bmatrix}  0       \\ \tfrac{1}{ \sqrt{2}}(1 - i)          \end{bmatrix}    \otimes      \begin{bmatrix}  0      \\ -0.92388 + 0.38268i          \end{bmatrix}    \otimes      \begin{bmatrix}  0      \\ -0.19509 - 0.98079i          \end{bmatrix}$'


display(Markdown(latex_good))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be fixed by replacing the newlines `\n` with a temporary character e.g. `~` which is not present in `latex_baad`.

```py
latex_baad = latex_baad.replace("\n","~")
latex_good = latex_baad.replace("~","")

display(Markdown(latex_good))
```

Answer (score 1):

use `replace` to modify it in place, <your_string>.replace('substring to remove','substring to replace')

I would suggest making all "`\n\n`" into "`\n`", then all "`\n`" into `" "`

```
your_string.replace("\n\n","\n")
your_string.replace("\n", " ")
your_string.replace("////","//")
```

For raw (no escapes) I believe you just preface your string with [`r' '`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415259/convert-regular-python-string-to-raw-string).

like:

`string  = r'this will ignore escape characters \n\n'`

Comment: Thanks for this idea. I implemented similar idea answered below and worked.