# Substituting backlashes with forward slashes in a string

Tags: python, string, replace, backslash, rawstring

Edited question:
I am writing a python function that takes the string of a path as copy-pasted from windows (so with backslashes) and returns a string with forwardslashes, that can be used by python as a path. The problem arises with the combination of backlashes and other characters, like \n, \b...
Thanks to Coldspeed, I now have a function that sort of does the trick:

```
def back2forwardSlash(backSlash_string):    
    return backSlash_string.replace('\\', '/')
```

What's still unsatisfactory is that I have to call the function with the `r` before the string to read it as raw: `fileNamePath = back2forwardSlash(r'C:\Users\Dropbox\netCFD4\b30.137.nc')` This prevents passing a variable into the function, instead of pasting in the string. Or at least, I don't think I have a solution to that.

Comment: did you even try `backSlash_string.replace('\\', '/')` ?

Comment: Try following this advice: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26867674/4528269

Answer (score 1):

[The *pythonic* way of doing this would be using `string.replace`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46295600/substituting-backlash-by-forwardslash/46295689#comment79553612_46295600).

```
def foo(string):
    return string.replace('\\', '/')
```

---

Furthermore, the reason for your error is that a backslash can be taken as the start of an escape sequence, which is a group of characters that are interpreted differently from their representation. This means that the sequence `\b` is not two separate characters, but a single character `\b`, or `\x08`. So, you'll want to pass a raw string to your function:

```
print(foo(r'C:\Users\Dropbox\netCFD4\b30.137.nc'))
```

A raw string will treat the backslashes literally. The alternative would be to escape all your backslashes.

Comment: Thanks COLDSPEED. The replace method does it pretty well, but the problem is actually solved only by calling the function with the `r` before the argument string, as you have suggested. This is only partially satisfactory, as I cannot pass the function with a variable, but always have to manually paste the string after the `r`, to get it raw. At least, I don't think I have a solution.

Comment: @Pauli If your strings are coming in like this, there is a problem with the source. Also, no real way to make variables raw strings...