# Convert the return of os.path.join(x,x) to raw string?

Tags: python, shell, os.path

What would be the best way to have 'file' returned as a string to be read into shell.Run()?

```
for dirpath, subdirs, files in os.walk(SOMEDIR):
    for ext in files:
        if ext.endswith(".txt"):

            file = str(os.path.join(dirpath, ext))

            shell = win32com.client.Dispatch('WScript.Shell')
            os.chdir(PROGDIR)
            shell.Run(PROG + file)
```

The issue I'm having is 'file' is not in a format that shell.Run() can read because there is a space in the dirpath. i.e. (Z:\Some Directory\etc\etc).  Renaming the directory is not an option.

Comment: Can you put quotes around it before passing it in?

Comment: @BrenBarn could you be more specific? Put quotes around what exactly? String slice up file?

Comment: Please take a look at [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7262918/3219121)

Comment: the string needs to be exactly like the console - you can't do e.g. `c:> c:\program files\myprog\prog.exe` in the console either, if you try it, tab completion will change it to `c:> "c:\program files\myprog\prog.exe" arg1 arg2` etc...