# How do I convert a string to a string literal in python?

Tags: python, string, arcgis

I'm writing some code that uses an Onclick event to get some file paths. I need to make sure these file paths are literals to make sure they're correct so the rest of my code can run. Right now I think I'm getting the file paths as unicode. Essentially I need this:

```
u"File\location\extra\slash"
```

to be this:

```
r"File\location\extra\slash"
```

How do I do this? I haven't been able to find anyone who's actually been able to do this successfully and the documentation doesn't have any examples of this. I can't change how the function that gives me the file paths Onclick event works.

Here is the code in question:

```
class SetLayer(object):
    """Implementation for leetScripts_addin.button2 (Button)"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = True
        self.checked = False
    def onClick(self):
        self.a = pythonaddins.GetSelectedCatalogWindowPath()
        print self.a
        #code split up path here
        self.b = os.path.split(str(self.a))
        self.c = self.b[0]
        self.d = os.path.split(self.c)
        self.e = (self.b[1])
        self.f = (self.d[1])
        self.g = (self.d[0])
```

Comment: Refer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7262828/python-how-to-convert-string-literal-to-raw-string-literal

Comment: It sounds like you're mistaken about what you actually have, if you say you have `u"File\location\extra\slash"`. Also, unless you actually want to print output with an "r" on the front and double quotes, what you need isn't actually a string literal. Can you `print repr(your_current_string)` and show us what that displays?

Comment: isn't it just u"File\location\extra\slash".decode('utf-8')  ?

Comment: Can't check right now, but I believe `os.path.join(yourPath)` should produce a valid platform dependent path

Comment: after rereading, if you just need raw string to pass it somewhere else, this should work: `yourPath.encode('string-escape')`

Comment: your question does not make sense ... please provide actual code and actual output ... vs what you hope the output was or why you think it is incorrect

Comment: @JoranBeasley I did check and I was getting u"File\location\extra\slash" as output. I wanted the string to act like r"File\location\extra\slash" and didn't know how else to phrase the question. I'm editing my question to show some more code now.

Comment: @user2357112 that returns "u'File\\\\location\\\\extra\\\\slash" I don't understand why the u is part of that string.

Comment: @Steve: Code format it, please, so the backslashes display correctly. The `u` means it's a Unicode string.

Comment: @scope That returns "File\\location\\extra\\slash"

Comment: @user2357112 there is actually four slashes per slash in the output there. `"u'File\\\\location\\\\extra\\\\slash"`

Comment: @Steve `r"File\location\extra\slash"` returns `"File\\location\\extra\\slash"` as well, right?

Comment: @scope It does not. `r"File\location\extra\slash"` returns `File\location\extra\slash`

Comment: @Steve: Is that the output for `print repr(self.a)`, or for one of the later things in your code, or something else? The `"u'File\\\\location\\\\extra\\\\slash"` output you're getting suggests that you've accidentally mangled your string in several ways; it looks like your string is a bytestring containing most of the `repr` of a Unicode string, where the Unicode string had twice as many backslashes as it should.

Comment: @user2357112 I did this `self.b = os.path.split(repr(self.a))` and the output for `print self.g` was that mangled output. How do I fix this? What am I doing wrong with my strings?

Comment: @Steve: Show us the output of `print repr(self.a)`, and tell us what information you're trying to extract from that string.

Comment: @user2357112 It's `u'File\\location\\extra\\slash'` I'm trying to get `e = 'slash' f = 'extra' g = 'File\location'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comments, you have `a = u'File\\location\\extra\\slash'`, and you want to extract `e = 'slash'`, `f = 'extra'`, and `g = 'File\location'`. Nothing here requires converting strings to string literals; you've just gotten really confused by various levels of string escaping.

You'll need to decide whether `e`, `f`, and `g` should be Unicode strings or bytestrings. Unicode strings are probably the right choice, but I can't make that choice for you. Whatever you choose, you'll need to make sure you know whether you're dealing with Unicode strings or bytestrings at all times. Currently, `a` is a Unicode string.

If you want Unicode strings for `e`, `f`, and `g`, you can do

```
self.e, temp = os.path.split(self.a)
self.g, self.f = os.path.split(temp)
```

If you want bytestrings, you'll need to encode `self.a` with the appropriate encoding and then do the above `os.path.split` calls. What the appropriate encoding is will depend on your specific OS and application. `sys.getfilesystemencoding()` or `'utf-8'` are likely choices.

Comment: Where am I string escaping?

Comment: @Steve: The code you posted doesn't do any escaping, but raw string syntax auto-escapes backslashes, and `u"File\location\extra\slash"` looks like you mixed up two different levels of escaping manually. You also used `repr` wrong in the comments the first time (`repr` does some escaping; it's actually the closest thing to "convert a string to a string literal" that Python has, though that's not what you really need.)

Comment: How did I use it wrong? Is there a resource that I could use to learn more about how strings actually work? I wasn't aware that it made a difference.

Answer (score -3):

You can use eval.

```
MacBookPro:~ DavidLai$ python
Python 2.7.11 (default, Jan 22 2016, 08:29:18)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> x = u"File\location\extra\slash"
>>> y = eval("r\"" + x + "\"")
>>> y
'File\\location\\extra\\slash'
>>> type(y)
<type 'str'>
>>>
```

Comment: whoa nelly .... we dont need to go jump off a cliff yet ...  (as an aside your solution would not work if the path was `"File\next\location"`)

Comment: evaluating string that comes from js (eg web client side and probably untrusted users) is a really bad idea.

Comment: `eval('os.system('rm -rf /something/important')")` and this is just one random thing which could happen