# Replace regex in python

Tags: python, django

I have a text like this:

```
@110605!~~!Abhay_f!~~!Abhay%20Raj%20Fac!>>! @138547!~~!testvarun!~~!Varun%20Test%20User!>>! @136588!~~!jitendra_pathak!~~!Jitendra%20Pathak!>>! #gffj #varun okjjbbbd
```

and in this string I want to replace `!~~!` with `""`.

I am using a `template tag` and I used this method but it didn't work for me:

```
@register.filter("metioned_user_text_encode")
def metioned_user_text_encode(string, args):
    search = args.split(args[0])[1]
    replace = args.split(args[0])[2]

    return re.sub(search, replace, string)
```

In my template:-

```
result_data_for_editing.newsText | metioned_user_text_encode:"/l(u+)pin/m\1gen"
```

Comment: Did you consider template strings are not [raw strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7262918/1600649)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I completely misunderstood your intentions, you are asking one thing but your code shows a different expected behavior than the one you ask for.
I will try to answer both cases:

---

**Case 1:**

You expect to get a multitude of separators like `!~~!` or `!>>!` etc., and you need a regex to replace all of them with an empty string (`''`).

Try the following:

```
import re

SEPARATORS = [
    '!~~!', 
    '!>>!', 
    other separators...
]

@register.filter("metioned_user_text_encode")
def metioned_user_text_encode(string):       
    return re.sub('|'.join(SEPARATORS), '', string)
```

Explanation:

- The `|` regex operator ensures that our pattern will try to match every separator given in `SEPARATORS` with the given string (`s`).
- The [`re.sub()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) will return the string with every pattern matching any of our `SEPARATORS`, replaced by the empty string.

---

**Case 2:**

You will receive as arguments a series of separators and an equally sized series of replacements for those separators. In that case, try:

```
@register.filter("metioned_user_text_encode")
def metioned_user_text_encode(string, args):
    returned_string = string
    search = args.split(args[0])[1]
    replace = args.split(args[0])[2]

    for i in range(len(search)):
        returned_string = re.sub(search[i], replace[i], returned_string)

    return returned_string
```

Explanation:

- The `for` loop will traverse the `search` and `replace` lists for every separator and the corresponding replacement.
- The [`re.sub()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) will return in each iteration, the `returned_string` with the `search[i]` separator replaced by the `replace[i]` substitute.

---

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the fileinput module which makes find and replace easy

```
import fileinput

with fileinput.FileInput(inputFile, inplace=True, backup='.back') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line.replace(textToSearch, textToReplace), end='')
```

Or you can use the replace method

```
str.replace("!~~!", "")
```

Comment: `str.replace("!~~!", "")` should work. where `str` is the name of the string.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
a = '@110605!~~!Abhay_f!~~!Abhay%20Raj%20Fac!>>! @138547!~~!testvarun!~~!'
b = a.replace(!~~!,'""')
print(b)
```