# How do a print a backslash-escaped string to output '\n' in Python?

Tags: python

```
In [4]: import re

In [5]: print(re.escape('\n'))
\


In [6]: print(re.escape(r'\n'))
\\n

In [7]: print(r'\n')
\n

In [8]: print('\n')


In [9]: print('\\n')
\n
```

The third example `print(r'\n')` gives the output I want (also the last example).

BUT the string I want to print is a variable that was not defined as a raw string.

Needless to say I cannot manually add backslashes to the string.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7262828/python-how-to-convert-string-literal-to-raw-string-literal See the fourth answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `repr()` to print a value as Python code:

```
print(repr('\n'))
```

...will emit:

```
'\n'
```

---

If you want to strip leading and trailing characters, then:

```
print(repr('\n')[1:-1])
```

...will emit only

```
\n
```

...but this is not futureproof (some strings may be emitted with different quoting, if not today, then in future implementations; including the literal quotes in output is thus the safe option).

---

Note that in a format string, you can use the `!r` modifier to indicate that you want `repr()` applied:

```
print('Value: {!r}'.format('\n'))
```

...will emit:

```
Value: '\n'
```

Comment: Nice one, thank you!  I am happy with the quoted output.   This also works in my actual case which is more like `print('wtf {}'.format(repr('\n')))` --> 
`wtf '\n'`

Comment: There are better answers in that case -- you can use the format string itself to indicate that you want `repr()` to be applied. See edit.