# Python 3: Represent bytestring as a string (without decoding)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a builtin way to "convert" a bytestring to a unicode string?
I don't want to decode it, I want the string i see on print without the "b".

e.g.
Input:

```
b'\xb5\xb5\xb5\xb5\r\n1'
```

output:

```
'\xb5\xb5\xb5\xb5\r\n1'
```

I've tried iterating over the byte string, but that gives me a list of integers:

```
my_bytestring = b'%PDF-1.4\n%\x93\x8c\x8b\x9e'

my_string = ""
my_list = []
for char in my_bytestring:
    my_list.append(char)
    my_string += str(char)
print(my_list)   # -> list of ints
print(my_string) # -> string of converted ints
```

I get:

```
[37, 80, 68, 70, 45, 49, 46, 52, 10, 37, 147, 140, 139, 158]
```

I want:

```
['%', 'P', 'D', 'F', '-', '1', '.', '4', '\\', 'n', '%', '\\', 'x', '9', '3', '\\', 'x', '8', 'c', '\\', 'x', '8', 'b', '\\', 'x', '9', 'e']
```

Comment: But they're both technically the same string... c.f: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7262828/python-how-to-convert-string-literal-to-raw-string-literal

Comment: None of the answers there do what I want though. They all decode or start from a unicode string. I amended the question to show what i get vs what i need.

Comment: Where is the bytestring coming from? I.E: Why can't you just do `r'...'` and not `b'...'`

Comment: Do you want the result to contain literal `\ `, `x`, `b`, etc.?

Comment: The bytestrings are files with unknown encodings. I need them as unicode strings to use as windows filenames. Python can obviously do it, or it wouldn't be possible to represent the bytestring on my screen (which IS unicode).

Comment: I could've sworn your expected output was a raw string just a little while ago...

Comment: @tobias_k.  With. I can always strip them if they are there, once i have a list/string

Comment: You're asking two different questions here. The first string is treated like a normal string (i.e. `b'\xb5'` becomes `'\xb5'`), while the 2nd string is treated like a raw string (i.e. `b'\xb5'` becomes `r'\xb5'`).

Comment: I should have just used 2 examples that couldn't 'unicode-escape'. I wasn't expecting so many responses saying to use decode after I said it didn't work, lol. (I wont change it now it has answers tho)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [[Python]: **chr**(*i*)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr) function:

> ```
> >>> b = b"\xb5\xb5\xb5\xb5\r\n1"
> >>> s = "".join([chr(i) for i in b])
> >>> s
> 'µµµµ\r\n1'
> >>> len(b), len(s)
> (7, 7)
> ```

As @hop mentioned, it would be better to use this method:

> ```
> >>> s0 = b.decode(encoding="unicode_escape")
> >>> s0
> 'µµµµ\r\n1'
> >>> len(s0)
> 7
> ```

However, looking at your 2<sup>nd</sup> example, it seems you need [[Python]: **repr**(*object*)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr):

> ```
> >>> my_bytestring = b'%PDF-1.4\n%\x93\x8c\x8b\x9e'
> >>> l = [i for i in repr(my_bytestring)][2:-1]
> >>> l
> ['%', 'P', 'D', 'F', '-', '1', '.', '4', '\\', 'n', '%', '\\', 'x', '9', '3', '\\', 'x', '8', 'c', '\\', 'x', '8', 'b', '\\', 'x', '9', 'e']
> >>> len(my_bytestring), len(l)
> (14, 27)
> ```

Comment: don't invent your own `.decode()` use the `unicode_escape` encoding

Comment: Thanks. Just changing the str(char) to chr(char) in my code did the job!

Comment: Thank you @hop, I'll add it.

Comment: Your links look like they've been inserted by some kind of script. May I ask where I can find this script? It looks useful.

Comment: @Aran-Fey: Unfortunately I didn't have the time to automate it yet, so it's all manual (monkey work) :) .

Answer (score 1):

Technically you cannot get from bytes to strings without decoding, but there is a codec that does what you want:

```
>>> b = b'\xb5\xb5\xb5\xb5\r\n1'
>>> s = b.decode('unicode_escape')
>>> s
'µµµµ\r\n1'
>>> print(s)
µµµµ
1
```

There is also `raw_unicode_escape`. You can read about the differences in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html?highlight=unicode_escape#text-encodings)

I very much doubt that there is a use case for having binary data in a unicode string.

Comment: Doesn't work for the second string. Gives: UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 11-14: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: @Yobmod I can't reproduce that. `b'%PDF-1.4\n%\x93\x8c\x8b\x9e'.decode('unicode_escape')` returns `'%PDF-1.4\n%\x93\x8c\x8b\x9e'`.

Answer (score -2):

The PDF payload obviously isn't utf-8 encoded, or other encodings. They are raw data, not any form of text.

BUT there is an encoding that mantains all the characters with code from 0 to 255:

```
data = data.decode("latin1")
```

This changes the data type from bytes to str.

It isn't a brilliant solution because it consumes cpu time and memory, creating a new object, but it is the only one.

**It is a nuisance there isn't an instruction in Python to just change the data type, from bytes to str, without processing.**