# How to pass values to python function by executing instructions input as string?

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

I have a function:

```
def foo(a=0, b=0, c=0, val=0, someotherval=0):  
    print val + someotherval
```

This function is called inside a file `bar.py`. When I run `bar.py` from the console, I want to pass the arguments to the function as a string:

```
>>python bar.py "val=3"
```

So the function `foo` interprets it as:

```
foo(val=3)
```

I have attempted to use the `exec` command. In my `bar.py` file:

```
import sys
cmdlinearg = sys.argv[1]    # capturing commandline argument
foo(exec(cmdlinearg))
```

But I get a syntax error.
I understand that I can just pass the argument values themselves, but with a function with many arguments, I do not want the end user to enter 0s for unneeded arguments:

```
>>python bar.py "0" "0" "0" "3"
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Just use [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html)

Comment: The argparse-based solutions are probably what you are looking for, but you could do `eval("foo(" + sys.argv[1] +")")`. Bear in mind that [the use of eval() is questionable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/is-using-eval-in-python-a-bad-practice).

Comment: From [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428117/casting-raw-strings-python) `cmdlinearg.encode('string-escape')` for pre Py3 `cmdlinearg.encode('unicode-escape')` for Py3.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have no concern for safety, you can just do

```
exec('foo(%s)' % sys.argv[1])
```

Or this:

```
def getdict(**vals):
    return vals
kwargs = exec('getdict(%s)' % sys.argv[1])
foo(**kwargs)
```

However, if your concern is the user's ease of use, maybe you should take a look at [argparse](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html).

Answer (score 2):

I would rather do this the proper way and use argparse.

Your command line interface would look such as:

```
bar.py --a 0 --b 0 --c 0 --val 0 --someotherval 0
```

And the code something along:

```
import argparse

def main():
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  parser.add_argument('a', type=int, default=0)
  ...
  args = parser.parse_args()
  foo(a=args.a, b=args.b, c=args.c, var=args.val, someotherval=args.someotherval)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Comment: you can also do `foo(**vars(args))` if all the arguments pertain to `foo`. (`vars` converts to a dictionary, `**` unpacks it)

Comment: @NightShadeQueen You could do that if the cmd line args match the function parameters. It's just that as the python zen mentions "explicit is better than implicit". I wouldn't like the idea of the code failing when adding a new cmd line argument (say --debug or whatever)

Answer (score 1):

How about using the [argparse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html) for parsing the command line arguments?

Example -

```
import argparse

def foo(a=0, b=0, c=0, val=0, someotherval=0):  
    print(val + someotherval)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Some Parser')
parser.add_argument('-a','--a',default=0,type=int,help="value for a")
parser.add_argument('-b','--b',default=0,type=int,help="value for a")
parser.add_argument('-c','--c',default=0,type=int,help="value for a")
parser.add_argument('-v','--val',default=0,type=int,help="value for a")
parser.add_argument('-s','--someotherval',default=0,type=int,help="value for a")
args = parser.parse_args()
foo(a=args.a,b=args.b,c=args.c,val=args.val,someotherval=args.someotherval)
```

Then you can call and get results like -

```
>python a.py
0

>python a.py --val 10
10

>python a.py --val 10 --someotherval 100
110
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this library:
http://click.pocoo.org

It may be useful in your case.

```
import click

@click.command()
@click.option('-a', default=0)
@click.option('-b', default=0)
@click.option('-c', default=0)
@click.option('--val', default=0)
@click.option('--someotherval', default=0)
def foo(a, b, c, val, someotherval):  
    print val + someotherval

if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo()
```

However, you have to add use options as arguments, not strings:

```
>> python bar.py --val=3
```

Answer (score -2):

You could just default the values for the other parameters if you know that they are never going to enter them.

```
foo(0,0,exec(cmdlinearg),0)
```

Comment: That won't work. One user might want to call foo(a=4), another might want to call foo(b=3, somotherval=10).