# Windows path with spaces in python

Tags: python

I have a problem with passing windows path to a function in python. Now, if I hard code the path everything actually works. So, my code is:

```
from pymatbridge import Matlab
lab = Matlab(executable=r'"c:\Program Files \MATLAB\bin\matlab.exe"')
lab.start()
```

This works fine as I am using the raw string formatting to the hard-coded string. Now, the issue is that the string is passed as a variable. So, imagine I have a variable like:

```
path="c:\Program Files \MATLAB\bin\matlab.exe"
```

Now, I am unable to figure out how to get the equivalent raw string from this. I tried may things like `shlex.quote(path)` and this makes issue with the `\b`. Without conversion to the raw string, the space in `Program Files` causes a problem, I think.

Comment: Try "\\" instead of "\"

Comment: remove `"` or `'`.  just use `r'c:\Program Files \MATLAB\bin\matlab.exe'` is OK

Comment: Possible duplicate of [whitespaces in the path of windows filepath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14852140/whitespaces-in-the-path-of-windows-filepath)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [casting raw strings python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428117/casting-raw-strings-python)

Answer (score -1):

```
def testpath(path):
    print path

testpath(path='c:\\Program Files \\MATLAB\\bin\\matlab.exe')
```

output is:

```
c:\Program Files \MATLAB\bin\matlab.exe
```

If you are facing issues with space between `Program Files` use `Progra~1` instead