# write escaped character to file so that the character is visible

Tags: python, python-3.x, escaping

I want to write "\t" to a file. Not a "tab character", but literally "\t".
How do I do this? It has been driving me crazy for more than an hour; everything I try produces an actual "tab character" (empty space).

Why would I want this? Because I'm generating a config file with a ConfigParser() which also includes some delimiters, and I want that file to be human-readable. I do not consider empty space readable.

EDIT: sorry, the problem was not clear: I want to do this for variables that contain strings. So writing "\\t" is not an option. I must write the value of a variable containing an escaped character to a file in a manner ideologically equivalent to:

```
v = "\t"
write(v)
```

without changing the definition of `v` (though operations on `v` are OK)
It seems impossible to change `v` into "\\t" after it has been defined as "\t".

Comment: did you try '\\t' ?

Comment: sorry, I edited the question so my problem is more clear

Comment: `v.replace("\t","\\t")` can be an option?

Comment: You can define your string as raw doing v = r"\t". Take a look in this question for an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41068918/cant-escape-escape-characters-in-string/41069081#41069081

Comment: Does this answer your question? [casting raw strings python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428117/casting-raw-strings-python)

Answer (score 5):

You need to escape the backslash so it won't be interpreted as a special character:

```
file_handle.write("\\t")
```

**EDIT:** It looks like your best option will be to use python's excellent `string.replace()` function:

```
>>> v = "aaa \t bbb"
>>> print v
aaa      bbb
>>> x = v.replace("\t", "\\t")  # <-- replace all '\t' in string with '\\t'
>>> print x
aaa \t bbb
```

Note: `v` will be unchanged, since strings are immutable in python

**EDIT 2:**

Looks like converting to a raw string will take care of escapeing all escaped characters for you:

```
>>> a = 'aaa\nbbb\n\tccc'
>>> print a
aaa
bbb
        ccc
>>> b = a.encode('string-escape')
>>> print b
aaa\nbbb\n\tccc
```

Comment: sorry, I edited the question so my problem is more clear

Comment: @PDiracDelta edited, i think this will be what you need.  I'm using 2.7, but it should be the same as 3 AFAIK

Comment: thanks for the hint, although this is not a general solution for any escape char - I still need to hardcode each possible escaped character. But for my practical purposes, it will do :-)

Comment: @PDiracDelta  I can't seem to get it to work for `v.replace('\\', '\\\\')`.  Asked a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41068918/cant-escape-escape-characters-in-string

Comment: also see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428117/casting-raw-strings-python

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> repr('\t')
"'\\t'"
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr

Answer (score 0):

Escape it.

Instead of writing `\t` write `\\t`

Comment: sorry, I edited the question so my problem is more clear

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume v is 'foo'.
You need the escape your single backslash.

```
v = '\\t %s' % v
print(v)
```

returns:

```
\t foo
```

Comment: sorry, I edited the question so my problem is more clear

Answer (score 0):

I've found a decoder workaround!

```
from codecs import getencoder as ge, getdecoder as gd
v = "\t"
ge("unicode-escape")(v)[0]
v = gd("utf-8")(byteDelim)[0]
write(v)
```

using the encoder one can introduce the extra "\" to make a tuple `(b'\\t', 1)`. Then deconstruct the byte-like string in the tuple using another decoder that does *not* remove the "\", like `utf-8`.