# Can't escape escape characters in string

Tags: python, string, escaping

In an attempt to answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41063524/write-escaped-character-to-file-so-that-the-character-is-visible/41063555#comment69344460_41063555), I managed to get the string to `print` the escape characters by escaping the backslash.

When I try to generalize it to escape all escaped characters, it seems to do nothing:

```
>>> a = "word\nanother word\n\tthird word"
>>> a
'word\nanother word\n\tthird word'
>>> print a
word
another word
        third word
>>> b = a.replace("\\", "\\\\")
>>> b
'word\nanother word\n\tthird word'
>>> print b
word
another word
        third word
```

but this same method for specific escape characters, it does work:

```
>>> b = a.replace('\n', '\\n')
>>> print b
word\nanother word\n    third word
>>> b
'word\\nanother word\\n\tthird word'
```

Is there a general way to achieve this?  Should include `\n`, `\t`, `\r`, etc.

Comment: There are no literal backslashes to match in your strings. The *literal* contains the two-character sequence `\n` to *specify* a newline, but Python converts that to a single, literal linefeed character in the resulting `str` object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define your string as raw using r'text', like in the code below:

```
a = r"word\nanother word\n\tthird word"
print(a)
word\nanother word\n\tthird word

b = "word\nanother word\n\tthird word"
print(b)
word
another word
        third word
```

Comment: Raw string are exactly what I was looking for, thanks!