# how to automatically escape control-characters in a Python string

Tags: python, escaping, control-characters

I have strings with control-characters in them, and I want to make them visible (for printing documentation of them, for instance).

For example, I have

```
dialect = csv.sniffer().sniff(csvfile.read(1024))
```

and I want to print the contents of

```
dialect.lineterminator
```

This obviously contains control-character(s).  They don't become printable by sticking a "\" in front of them.  I'd like to see \n \r or both, as appropriate.

As I'm using Python 3, similar questions have proposed using str.encode, such as

```
    dialect.lineterminator.encode('unicode-escape')
```

but if I print this, I get

```
    b'\\r\\n'
```

which is, in spite of its appearance, just two bytes.  I want a unicode string such as

```
    "\\r\\n"
```

which is a 4-character string.  I'm not after the unicode encoding, but the escape sequence.

Comment: It turns out the answer is more simple than I thought possible.  The result I want is exactly `repr(dialect.lineterminator)` or possibly `repr(dialect.lineterminator)[1:-1]`

Answer (score 9):

You can just convert the string to a raw string:

```
>>> a = 'foo\nbar'
>>> print a
foo
bar
>>> print a.encode('string-escape')
foo\nbar
```

Note:  this is for Python2 only, in 3 the equivalent is `str.encode('unicode_escape')` AFAIK

[Here's a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41068918/cant-escape-escape-characters-in-string) I recently asked.

Comment: This is far from perfect as it escapes any special character, not just control characters.