# Save string to file without converting newlines using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, newline

I want to save the following string into a file using Python. The string includes **\n** which I don't want to be converted into a new line. Here is my code:

```
text = 'hello "\n" world'
file = open("file.js", "w")
file.write(text)
file.close()
```

When I open `file.js` I get the following output (which is expected):

```
hello "
" world
```

Is there any way to save the file without the newlines being forced to be be converted? My desired output to the file would be:

```
hello "\n" world
```

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41063524/write-escaped-character-to-file-so-that-the-character-is-visible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by **escaping backslashes** (`\\`). So, you can just escape the newline character like:

```
text = 'hello "\\n" world'
```

You can also use something called **raw-strings** which automatically escapes the backslashes for you. These are strings that precede with an `r`:

```
text = r'hello "\n" world'
```

#### Output

---

When written to a file, you will get the following, without any newline character in the middle:

```
'hello "\n" world'
```