# How to write a string that has new lines (\n) to a file in one line in Python?

Tags: python, string

Say I have a string `str="abc\n\ndef"` and I want to write it to a file in a single line as it is. I use `file.write(str)`, however, the new lines will be expanded and the file will be something like

```
abc


def
```

Is there a way I could write it into a single line?

Comment: Well you did use 2 `\n`'s.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41063524/write-escaped-character-to-file-so-that-the-character-is-visible

Comment: You know that `"abc\n\ndef"` is the representation of the string and not the content? That string has 6 characters: a, b, c, d, e, f and 2 newline characters. There is no backslash and no character "n" in the string. So "write as it is" is **not** what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use r-strings if you don't want `\n` to turn into newline:

```
str=r"abc\n\ndef"
file.write(str)
```

Comment: How to use r string when you already have a variable (i.e. you do not have access to the definition of the string)?

Comment: @JohnM. It wasn't clear what you had.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean you want a file with "abc\n\ndef". If so you can by escaping the escape character:
`str="abc\\n\\ndef"`

Answer (score 0):

```
str="abc\n\ndef"
file.write(repr(str))
```

this prints `'abc\n\ndef'`

EDIT

if you do not want the ' ', use:

```
str="abc\n\ndef"
file.write(str.replace("\n", "\\n"))
```

Comment: Nice idea, but now you have the single quotes in the output.

Comment: use str.replace("\\n", "\n") for parsing \n as newline when writing to file