# Print strings with backslashes in Python 2.7

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, escaping

I'm getting the strings passed in and want to print the buffer in raw format (printing the double backslash as is)
How do I tell the string.format() this is a 'raw' string and don't use the backslash character?

```
>>> machines=['\\JIM-PC', '\\SUE-PC', '\\ANN-PC']
>>> for machine in machines:
...     print 'Machine Found %s' % (machine)
...
Machine Found \JIM-PC
Machine Found \SUE-PC
Machine Found \ANN-PC
```

Comment: Try `print(repr(machine))`

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do it would be to just double down on your slashes, since "\\" is considered a single slash character.

```
machines=['\\\\JIM-PC','\\\\SUE-PC','\\\\ANN-PC']
for machine in machines:
    print 'Machine Found %s' % (machine)
```

You could also use the method str.encode('string-escape'):

```
machines=['\\JIM-PC','\\SUE-PC','\\ANN-PC']
for machine in machines:
    print 'Machine Found %s' % (machine.encode('string-escape'))
```

Alternatively, you could assign the value as well, if you want the encoding to stick to the variables for later use.

```
machines=['\\JIM-PC','\\SUE-PC','\\ANN-PC']
for machine in machines:
    machine = machine.encode('string-escape')
    print 'Machine Found %s' % (machine)
```

I found the str.encode('string-escape') method here: [casting raw strings python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428117/casting-raw-strings-python)

Hope this helps.

Edit

Re Chris: print(repr(machine)) works too, as long as you don't mind that it includes the quote marks.

Comment: thanks allan, the ''.encode('string-escape') is what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

The string literal `'\\JIM-PC'` **does not contain a double backslash**; what you see is the *representation* of a single backslash in a regular string literal.

This is easily shown by looking at the length of the string, or iterating over its individual characters:

```
>>> machine = '\\JIM-PC'
>>> len(machine)
7
>>> [c for c in machine]
['\\', 'J', 'I', 'M', '-', 'P', 'C']
```

To create a string containing a double backslash, you can either use a [raw string literal](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals): `r'\\JIM-PC'`, or represent two backslashes appropriately in a regular string literal: `'\\\\JIM-PC'`.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24085680/why-do-backslashes-appear-twice