# How to add a "r" automatically when enter path in Python?

Tags: python

I wrote a short script to turn the '\' in the path to '\\'

```
def useinR(address):
    address_list=address.split("\\")
    r_address="\\\\".join(address_list)
    print(r_address)
```

I need to add an "r" in front of the path to make sure it works well, as [This Question mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347791/unicode-error-unicodeescape-codec-cant-decode-bytes-cannot-open-text-file)

so when I use that script, I need to enter

```
useinR(r"F:\Study\UWA\CITS4009\w11_example\protein.txt")
```

instead of

```
useinR("F:\Study\UWA\CITS4009\w11_example\protein.txt")
```

How can we avoid enter the r before path?

I tried `r+address` , but in that case the "r" is in the string, so it doesn't work

Why I need to do this:

We cannot use file path like `F:\abc.txt` in RStudio

we need to enter `F:\\abc.txt`

Comment: ``address=address`` -this line is useless.

Comment: Does [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2428117/9209546) help?

Comment: The whole function is useless. There's no reason to double the backslashes like that.

Comment: We actually don't have proper canonical for these kinds of questions, so if someone wants to post an answer that explains why converting existing strings to "raw strings" is nonsensical, that would be great. I recently looked through all the "raw string" questions I could find, and I couldn't find one with that kind of answer. The closest thing we have is [this unclear garbage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415259/python-raw-strings).

Comment: sorry, I deleted that address=address. It was the remain code when I tried r+address

Comment: Why I wrote this is we cannot use path like F:\ abc.txt in R, we need to use F:\\ abc.txt

Comment: I'll just give you a short answer here: *"How can we avoid enter the r before path?"* We don't. Using the `r` is the correct solution.

Comment: Look into using the `os` package from the standard library. https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax `r"string\with\slashes"` indicates that the string literal should be treated as a [raw string](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals), which means that slashes do not denote unicode control sequences in the string.

If you want to pass *string literals* to your `useinR` function, you need to add the raw string prefix. The prefix can't be applied in front of a variable because it relates only to literals.